# SSH via gateway with SSH keys on Gateway

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I want to set up my company's server as a gateway to all of our client's servers. So that people I work with can simply 'proxy on through' without needing to set up SSH keys on their machine. I.e.

```
[My local box] -> [Our Company Server (with SSH keys)] -> [Client's server]
```

So far I have this in my .ssh/config

```
Host client-server
    User myclient
    ProxyCommand ssh -o Compression=no gateway netcat -w 3 %h %p
    Compression yes

host gateway
    HostName company-server
    User me
    Compression yes
```

However this still asks for a password for myclient@client-server. I want it to use the ssh key on gateway. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can start another ssh session right from your `.ssh/authorized_keys` file:

```
command="/usr/bin/ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_<user> <server>",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 <key-data>
```

You will still need to create a local key file and add it to the target user/server `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Does this mean there will be no keys for the client's server on the local server?

Comment: @MatthewHaworth Can you clarify this a bit? You are talking about known_hosts, inbound or outbound connections?